# Easy to use (Gui Win) Version Control Software

Tags: git, user-interface, version-control, latex

I'm in search for a friend who studies economic science for an easy Version Control Software. For the moment he needs it for his thesis which has to be written in LaTeX. Since he has to learn LaTeX too (and he has enough problems with it) the VCS should be easy to use - at best with Gui for Windows. He is the only one who has to use the VCS.

A few years ago I used a VCS for the same purpose, but I can't find it any more. It was a bit like Git. It made in the working directory a hidden directory where it stored it's information.

I tried to teach him Git, but he said it is to complicated (I only use Git on command line and don't know any good Gui's) with his thesis and LaTeX.

Is there a good Gui for Git or an easy to learn/use VCS (it should be free)?

Thanks

Comment: Off topic here but direct your friend to Subversion with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your friend doesn't want to use SVN there is nice GUI for Mercurial: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/. 
Mercurial is really easy to learn. There are lot of tutorials for quick learning (for example: http://hginit.com/, https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide/).

Comment: I think he will be happy with the hginit turorial - not too much "techtalk" ;) SourceTree looks good too.

Comment: I found a better GUI for my friend http://easyhg.org/ it seems very easy to use with only the essentials in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.net/), it has nice and clean GUI and I think it's easy to use. You can create local repo in any empty folder then you can checkout, edit and commit. It has build in repo browser, diff and some useful tools. Go to screenshot section (http://tortoisesvn.net/screenshots.html) to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) — it's slick and flashy but does not try to enforce a non-Git workflow on you.

Note that if your friend is about to maintain their project on Github, he could as well just grab [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) which is really a no-brainer point-and-click solution.